# xmlhttprequest always return with status code 0 for firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make asynchronous calls using xmlhttprequest object
so it completely works fine in internet explorer but for firefox it wont work

a small code snippet of problem

```
if (req.readyState == 4)
{
  if (req.status == 200) //here firefox gives status code always 0 and for IE works fine
  {
     //read response              
  } else {
    alert("There was a problem with the request.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

issue resolved its due to misunderstanding about firefox with status code
on making XMLHttpRequest as non-HTTP requests. 
So for that it returns status code as 0

Comment: i have the same issue. can you explain more about what the answer and how you solve it?